# best strategy to test bivariate data

Tags: p-value, copula, bivariate

Here's a revised version of your text:

I have two sets of data: Intensity and Duration. For each set, I possess both observation data and model data, denoted as (I_obs, I_mod) and (D_obs, D_mod) respectively. I put a example of my data structured bellow.

To assess whether the I_obs set belongs to the same population as I_mod and similarly for D_obs and D_mod, I applied the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, utilizing the p-value. Basically the KS test between the first column and the third column and the KS test between the second and the fourth column.

Now, I am interested in extending this analysis to a bivariate approach. Specifically, I want to examine if (I_obs, D_obs) and (I_mod, D_mod) belong to the same population. To achieve this, I considered estimating the copula that best fits (I_obs, D_obs) and another for (I_mod, D_mod). However, I have encountered instances where the copulas obtained are of the same type.

I am curious if you are familiar with any non-parametric tests that could assist me in this direction. It's essential to note that my data exhibit no particular structure, such as a Gaussian distribution.

```
I_obs, D_obs, I_mod, D_mod
0.45,   0.63,   0.09,   0.63
0.64,   0.02,   0.20,   0.90
0.08,   0.44,   0.51,   0.72
0.27,   0.94,   0.83,   0.44
0.59,   0.39,   0.24,   0.59
0.76,   0.12,   0.95,   0.41
0.65,   0.29,   0.62,   0.18
0.48,   0.96,   0.20,   0.75
0.32,   0.41,   0.21,   0.41
0.80,   0.17,   0.96,   0.91
0.49,   0.94,   0.38,   0.03
0.76,   0.59,   0.35,   0.63
```

Comment: What is "observation data" and "model data"? What are the variables?  Also, the p value from the KS test only tests if they are significantly different, not if they are the same, and it suffers from all the usual problems of p values, especially that it is partly dependent on sample size.

Comment: I put an example. The problem is that KS works only for , let say, 1D vs 1D datasets

Answer (score 0):

You might use the non-parametric Wilcoxon signed rank test for paired measurements to determine if the distribution of $I_{obs}$ is significantly different from the distribution of $I_{mod}$.  You could also use the non-parametric Spearman rank correlation test to determine if the pairs of variables are associated.  That is, whether the correlation coefficient, $r_S$, between e.g. $I_{obs}$ and $I_{mod}$ is not equal to zero.  In any software package, this would merely be a default run of Spearman rank correlation between two variables (bivariate), since the default is a null hypothesis of $r_S=0$.

Comment: The Wilcoxon signed rank test, if I have understood correctly, could substitute the KS test. What about the bi-variate approach? Basically compare the columns 1 and 2 with the columns 3, 4. A sort of 2D comparison.

Comment: Would use canonical correlation analysis ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) for that, i.e., determining degree of association between sets of variables.  If they're not normally (Gaussian) distributed, you can use their ranks, or convert ranks to percentiles, and then input percentiles into the inverse cumulative normal function to get a Z-score, $Z=\Phi^{-1}(pct)$,-- which is purely normally distributed with mean zero, and variance one.  (these are called van der Waerden scores).  Use the Z-scores as inputs in canonical correlation analysis.